# Read & convert sheet from an xlsx file into csv

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export-to-csv, analytics

I want to read a sheet from an excel xlsx file and convert that tab into a csv file using python. I can read xlsx file using pandas and write into csv file. But csv file is not in the correct format.Extracting few columns also not working.
[image: Input xlsx file]

********************Input xlsx file************************

Company abcommerce Holdings Inc
Bloomberg Ticker    abc US Equity
Email   abc@xyz.com
Model Upload Opt-Out (0 = No, 1 = Yes)  0

```
KPI Actual  Actual  Actual  Estimate    Estimate    Estimate    Estimate
    2018    2019    2020    2021    2022    2023    2024
```

Line Item       FY  FY  FY  FY  FY  FY  FY

Revenue     91.9    112.1   152.4   197.5   254.8   319.0   391.8
COGS (ex D&A)       21.9    27.0    34.1    46.8    58.0    69.7    82.0
OpEx (ex COGS)      86.0    99.0    122.8   139.1   163.2   184.0   201.2
EBITDA      -27.6   -38.4   -35.6   -32.3   -21.7   -1.6    29.6
D&A     10.3    2.6 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.8 2.9
Depreciation        1.8 2.6 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.8 2.9
Amortization        8.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
EBIT        -38.0   -41.0   -38.7   -35.2   -24.5   -4.5    26.6
Interest Expense        0.8 1.4 3.1 3.1 3.1 3.1 3.1
EBT     -38.9   -42.6   -37.5   -37.1   -26.4   -6.4    24.7
Current Tax     0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.2
Deferred Tax
Net Income      -38.9   -49.9   -38.5   -37.1   -26.4   -6.4    19.5
Shares Outstanding      16.8    17.8    39.1    68.7    68.8    69.0    69.1
Common Dividends per Share          0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

Cash & Short-Term Investments       36.2    7.8 219.4   180.3   148.1   133.9   144.3
Working Capital - Assets (A/R, Inventory, Prepaid Exp)      17.0    23.9    34.6    36.7    43.9    52.0    61.2
Total Current Assets        53.1    31.7    254.1   217.0   192.0   185.9   205.5
PP&E, net       5.2 22.3    19.0    19.1    19.8    21.0    22.6
Intangible Assets, net
Goodwill
Other L-T Operating Assets      0.8 2.1 3.6 3.6 3.6 3.6 3.6
Total Long-Term Assets      6.0 24.4    22.6    22.7    23.4    24.6    26.2
Working Capital – Liabilities (A/P, Deferred Revenue)       26.7    28.8    42.7    42.8    44.9    46.4    48.1
Short-Term Debt     0.9 5.1 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2
Total Current Liabilities       27.6    33.9    45.9    46.0    48.1    49.6    51.2
Long-Term Debt      23.4    54.2    12.7    12.7    12.7    12.7    12.7
Total Long-Term Liabilities     26.5    55.7    14.0    14.0    14.0    14.0    14.0
Common Equity       0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
Retained Earnings       -224.7  -274.5  -313.4  -350.5  -376.8  -383.2  -363.7
Total Shareholders Equity       5.0 -33.5   216.8   179.7   153.3   146.9   166.5

Depreciation & Amortization     10.3    2.6 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.8 2.9
Change in Net Working Capital       4.6 -3.2    1.3 -1.9    -5.1    -6.5    -7.6

I tried below code to read excel file and write into csv file.

import pandas as pd
xls=pd.ExcelFile(xlsxfile)
df1=pd.read_excel(xls,"Sheet1")
df1.loc['1:3','D']  ## Column D has abc@xyz.com, abc US Equity values from row 1 to 3
df1.to_csv(path,sep=',',encoding='utf-8',index=False)

Console Output I got:
KeyError: 'the label [1:3] is not in the [index]'.

I'm expecting below output csv format file:

[image: Output csv file]
Author_Name Ticker Name Category    Line Item   Year    Period  Estimate/Actual Value
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Income Statement Inputs Revenue 2018    FY  Actual  91.867
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Income Statement Inputs Revenue 2019    FY  Actual  112.103
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Income Statement Inputs Revenue 2020    FY  Actual  152.368
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Income Statement Inputs Revenue 2021    FY  Estimate    197.5384303
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Income Statement Inputs Revenue 2022    FY  Estimate    254.7535894
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Income Statement Inputs Revenue 2023    FY  Estimate    318.9550221
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Income Statement Inputs COGS (ex D&A)   2018    FY  Actual  21.937
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Income Statement Inputs COGS (ex D&A)   2019    FY  Actual  27.023
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Income Statement Inputs COGS (ex D&A)   2020    FY  Actual  34.126
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Balance Sheet Inputs    Cash & Short-Term Investments   2018    FY  Actual  36.16
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Balance Sheet Inputs    Cash & Short-Term Investments   2019    FY  Actual  7.795
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Balance Sheet Inputs    Cash & Short-Term Investments   2020    FY  Actual  219.447
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Cash Flow Statement Inputs  Depreciation & Amortization 2018    FY  Actual  10.341
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Cash Flow Statement Inputs  Depreciation & Amortization 2019    FY  Actual  2.569
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Cash Flow Statement Inputs  Depreciation & Amortization 2020    FY  Actual  3.084
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Cash Flow Statement Inputs  Depreciation & Amortization 2021    FY  Actual  2.8446
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Cash Flow Statement Inputs  Change in Net Working Capital   2021    FY  Actual  -1.925190213
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Cash Flow Statement Inputs  Change in Net Working Capital   2022    FY  Actual  -5.147672185
abc@xyz.com abc US Equity   Cash Flow Statement Inputs  Change in Net Working Capital   2023    FY  Actual  -6.535871746

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
# Reading the spreadsheet twice (infos+data)
infos = (pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name="Data extraction",
                       header=None, usecols="D", nrows=3).squeeze().tolist())

data = (pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name="Data extraction", header=[5, 6, 7])
           .assign(Category=lambda x: x.pop(('Unnamed: 1_level_0', 'Unnamed: 1_level_1',
                                             'Unnamed: 1_level_2')).ffill())
           .iloc[1:, 1:].drop("KPI", axis=1, level=0))

# Reshaping the blocks
categories = (data.iloc[:, [0,-1]].droplevel([0, 1], axis=1)
                        .set_axis(["Line Item", "Category"], axis=1))

values = (data.iloc[:, 1:-1].melt(var_name=["Estimate/Actual", "Year", "Period"],
                                  value_name="Value", ignore_index=False).sort_index())

tickers = pd.DataFrame({"Author_Name": [infos[2]]*len(values),
                        "Ticker Name": [infos[1]]*len(values)})

# Making the final table
cols_to_use = ["Author_Name", "Ticker Name", "Category",
               "Line Item", "Year", "Period", "Estimate/Actual", "Value"]

out = (categories.join(values).reset_index()
         .sort_values(["index", "Category", "Line Item",
                       "Year", "Estimate/Actual", "Period"]).join(tickers)
          [cols_to_use].reset_index(drop=True))

#out.to_csv("output.csv", index=False) #uncomment this line to make a fresh .csv file
```

Output :

```
     Author_Name     Ticker Name                 Category                   Line Item   Year Period Estimate/Actual  Value
0    abc@xyz.com  BIGC US Equity  Income Statement Inputs                     Revenue   2018     FY          Actual   91.9
1    abc@xyz.com  BIGC US Equity  Income Statement Inputs                     Revenue   2019     FY          Actual  112.1
2    abc@xyz.com  BIGC US Equity  Income Statement Inputs                     Revenue   2020     FY          Actual  152.4
3    abc@xyz.com  BIGC US Equity  Income Statement Inputs                     Revenue   2021     FY        Estimate  197.5
4    abc@xyz.com  BIGC US Equity  Income Statement Inputs                     Revenue   2022     FY        Estimate  254.8
..           ...             ...                      ...                         ...    ...    ...             ...    ...  
198  abc@xyz.com  BIGC US Equity     Balance Sheet Inputs  Total Long-Term Liabilities  2020     FY          Actual   14.0
199  abc@xyz.com  BIGC US Equity     Balance Sheet Inputs  Total Long-Term Liabilities  2021     FY        Estimate   14.0
200  abc@xyz.com  BIGC US Equity     Balance Sheet Inputs  Total Long-Term Liabilities  2022     FY        Estimate   14.0
201  abc@xyz.com  BIGC US Equity     Balance Sheet Inputs  Total Long-Term Liabilities  2023     FY        Estimate   14.0
202  abc@xyz.com  BIGC US Equity     Balance Sheet Inputs  Total Long-Term Liabilities  2024     FY        Estimate   14.0

[203 rows x 8 columns]
```

*Spreadsheeet used :*

[image]